# Raw image data display

Tags: javascript, image

I am trying to display some raw image file formats in the browser window. After decoding, I end up with a raw array of pixels. Now I want to convert it to an Image element and set the src of the image element to the Blob created from the raw pixel data. However, browsers only support limited image formats and I am out of ideas on how to achieve this?

Is there a way of converting raw pixel data to an image url that can then be opened using normal DOM functionality? Speed is important here since decoding raw formats is already pretty slow.

Thank you.

Edit: Since speed is important therefore any methods that involve rendering pixels to canvas and then getting a data URL for the canvas are not viable.

Comment: Google for "uncompressed png". This needs a header with a fixed size, CRC32, and an extra byte per row of pixels (and for images >32K, some minimal extra processing).

Comment: Can you provide an example of raw array of pixel? What do u decode from?

Answer (score 1):

When you've a typed Uint8ClampedArray drawing to canvas and getting a data url is pretty fast, faster than any solution involving transformations into real binary blob data and getting a blob url.

If even milliseconds matter to you, you could use webgl and put the raw data into a texture and render it on a quad. This should be even faster since you would not need to let the browser parse the base64 n all that.

Still if performance is so important you would be better off writing an NaCl plugin or something. Javascript is not made to juggle a lot with binary data.

Comment: Writing a new NPAPI plugin is almost certainly not the right choice, since both Chrome and Firefox are moving to blocking them by default, and Chrome has announced plans to completely remove NPAPI support.

Comment: Oh didnt knew about that, so i guess NaCl is the way to go. I'll adjust my answer accordingly.